# Entity Framework creating incorrect foreign keys

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, key

I'm toying with a virtual parimutuel as an exercise in working with Entity Framework code-first. I have grasped most of the subtleties of working with it, but tonight I tweaked some organization of my database tables and EF just isn't setting up a constraint properly. Either that or I'm an idiot who is missing something.

Overview: There is a `Pools` table representing something you can bet on. There is a `PoolEventPair` that has a many to one relationship with the pool. The vast majority of the time this will be 1-to-1, but you could have something like a Daily Double where you bet on the winner of two races. Then there is the `ParimutuelEvent` table. This is a specific event like *the third race at Churchill Downs*. The event can occur in more than one pool such as the Win and Place pools. Then the `ParimutuelEntry` table contains the list of entrants in the event: *Quicksilver*, *Old Glue Pot*, *Beetlebaum*, etc. All that describes a tree of tables that are working just fine. (Diagram will appear below.)

From the `Pools` table is also a `Bet` table. There are many bets to a pool, thus a many-to-one relationship. While a bet can contain a single selection (*Quicksilver* to win) there is the possibility of multiple entrants (perfecta bet of *Beetlebaum* in first place and *Quicksilver* in second place). The `BetSelection` table is related to the `Bet` table and **also** to the `ParimutuelEntry` table. If you bet on *Quicksilver* there needs to be a relation with the specific entry.

All the above is in code-first and the diagram below is what I get when I see what's in SQL Server.
[image]
You'll notice that there is a many-to-one relationship between `ParimutuelEntry` and `Bet`. This is wrong. It should be something more like a 1-to-1 relationship between `BetSelection` and `ParimutuelEntry`. (The bad relation is highlighted.)

Here are the classes that built this. (A few irrelevant fields left out for clarity.):

```
    public abstract class Bet
    {
        public enum BetStatus
        {
             // values
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Pools")]
        public int PoolId { get; set; }
        public Pool Pool { get; set; } = null!;
        public BetStatus Status { get; set; } = BetStatus.Wagered;
        public DateTime StatusChange { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Expires { get; set; }
        public List<BetSelection> BetSelections { get; set; } = null!;
        public abstract string Description(string[] events);
    }
```

```
   public class BetSelection
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BetId { get; set; }
        public int ParimutuelEntryId { get; set; }
    }
```

```
   public class ParimutuelEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParimutuelEventId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public int? Position { get; set; } = null;      // final position after contest end
        public bool Scratched { get; set; }
        public List<Bet> Bets { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

I'm not sure it's relevant, but in case it is, here's the `Pools` table:

```
    public abstract class Pool
    {
        static protected DateTime _unixAdjust = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddHours(-6);

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool Closed { get; set; }
        public DateTime Open { get; set; }
        public int StartingPot { get; set; }
        public List<PoolEventPair>? PoolEventPairs { get; set; } = null!;
        public List<Bet> Bets { get; set; } = null!;

        [NotMapped]
        public int Deadline 
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)((PoolEventPairs!.OrderBy(x => x.ParimutuelEvent!.Start).Select(x=>x.ParimutuelEvent!.Start).First() - _unixAdjust).TotalSeconds);
            }
        }
        public abstract Bet BetFrom(BetInfo info);
        [NotMapped]
        public abstract string DisplayName { get; }
    }
```

Can someone tell me why the FK is pointing to the wrong table? How is `ParimutuelEntryId` ending up in the `Bet` table when there's no coded relationship between them? For astute readers, you'll notice the `Discriminator` column indicting that I'm using inheritance. I checked the hierarchy and there is no reference to the `ParimutuelEntry` table anywhere. Global search of the code only showed I tried to relate `ParimutualEntry` to `BetSelection`.

Comment: Is your question about the newer [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) or the older [entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework)?

Comment: The newest one: EF core

Comment: Then I'd suggest to edit the Question and add the `entity-framework-core` Tag, and probably remove `entity` and `frameworks`, so that your question might appear in the standard filters / web searches of the interested experts

Comment: Suggested change made

Comment: This terminology "*more* like a 1-to-1" is too vague. Either it is or it isn't. If you show what the data model should look like *exaclty* then we can probably help you.

Comment: Gert, the vast majority of racing bets have a single entry. There are exceptions. And I have pictures above and describe what the correct FK should be, but I'm not getting. I'm not sure what you'd like me to supply in addition.

Comment: @GertArnold Maybe this will help: https://i.imgur.com/rJzxCu1.png

Comment: There is a relationship: `List<Bet> Bets` in `ParimutuelEntry`. Try to change it into `public BetSelection BetSelection { get; set; }` and configure the relaionship in fluent API to be 1:1 with `ParimutuelEntryId` to be the FK.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you for your comment. I had a long Thanksgiving weekend to play with this and I think I hit that point you get over-tired and can't sort out your own mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be a victim of making things complicated for myself. I went back over my classes and noticed that I had two identically named `Bets` properties. For my own sanity in trying to work this out, I gave it a unique named. This changed nothing for EF when I tried to add a migration. But then as I returned to one of my lambda expressions, I realized that I wasn't correctly referencing the `BetSelection` class. When I cleaned up the `ParimutuelEntry` class it all fell in place. As I was writing this, I noticed that Gert Arnold left me a comment making the same observation. Thank you, Gert, you are spot-on.

```
    public class ParimutuelEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParimutuelEventId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public int? Position { get; set; } = null;      // final position after contest end
        public bool Scratched { get; set; }
        public List<BetSelection> BetSelections { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

And, behold, it all falls in place correctly:
[image: Table Diagram]